# Records are not selected from EQUI

Tags: abap, opensql

I am currently working on an application which requires all equipments from the EQUI table. When I look at the table via SE11, there are 225 entries.

When I try to select the equipments through a function module, I get a very different result.

```
  SELECT E~EQUNR, E~EQART, I~BEBER, Q~IWERK, I~TPLNR, K~EQKTX, K~SPRAS, E~GERNR, X~PLTXT
  FROM EQUI AS E
  INNER JOIN EQKT AS K ON K~EQUNR EQ E~EQUNR
  INNER JOIN EQUZ AS Q ON Q~EQUNR EQ E~EQUNR
  INNER JOIN ILOA AS I ON I~ILOAN EQ Q~ILOAN
  INNER JOIN IFLOTX AS X on X~TPLNR EQ I~TPLNR
  WHERE E~EQUNR LIKE @P_EQUNR
  AND I~BEBER LIKE @P_BEBER
  AND I~TPLNR LIKE @P_TPLNR
  AND Q~IWERK LIKE @P_IWERK
  AND E~GERNR LIKE @P_GERNR
  AND K~SPRAS EQ @IV_SPRAS
  AND X~SPRAS EQ @IV_SPRAS
  INTO TABLE @ET_EQUIPS.
```

When I query them with this select statement, I do get the same amount of results as the EQUI table, but without the other data I require.

```
  SELECT E~EQUNR, E~EQART
  FROM EQUI AS E
  INNER JOIN JEST AS J ON J~OBJNR EQ E~OBJNR
  INNER JOIN TJ02T AS T on T~ISTAT EQ J~STAT
  WHERE INACT NE 'X'
  AND J~STAT NE 'I0320'
  AND J~STAT NE 'I0076'
  INTO TABLE @ET_EQUIPS.
```

Any help on how to get the same amount of results with all the other data as well?

Comment: Try to exclude all the WHEREs consequently and turn the joins into `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. Simple!

Comment: I'll try that! Thanks!

Comment: Exactly what I needed! If you want, you can answer the question and I'll accept.

Comment: Added the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically it happens when some of your conditions are not met or the recordset is not presented in one of the joined tables. Try to use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and check all your WHERE conditions one by one.

You can start with the following statement:

```
SELECT E~EQUNR, E~EQART, I~BEBER, Q~IWERK, I~TPLNR, K~EQKTX, K~SPRAS, E~GERNR, X~PLTXT
  FROM EQUI AS E
 LEFT OUTER JOIN EQKT AS K ON K~EQUNR EQ E~EQUNR
 LEFT OUTER JOIN EQUZ AS Q ON Q~EQUNR EQ E~EQUNR
 LEFT OUTER JOIN ILOA AS I ON I~ILOAN EQ Q~ILOAN
 LEFT OUTER JOIN IFLOTX AS X on X~TPLNR EQ I~TPLNR
```